# Why doesn't my AM/PM time to 24 hour clock in C++ work? (hackerrank prob)

Tags: c++

I have been working on a AM/PM clock to 24-hour clock, and for some reason I am getting stuck. I am unsure of what assumption/mistake I am making. I have tried numerous test cases and can't seem to create the erroneous code that it is being rejected for.

It's a [hackerrank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/time-conversion?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen). I know there are solutions but I just want to know *why* my code doesn't work, because I want to understand what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string time;
    cin >> time;
    string str_hours = time.substr(0,2);
    string str_minutes = time.substr(3,2);
    string str_seconds = time.substr(6,2);
    string period = time.substr(8,2);

    int hours = stoi(str_hours);
    if(period.compare("PM") == 0) {
      hours += 12;
    }
    str_hours = to_string(hours);
    if(hours < 10) {
      str_hours.insert(0,"0");
    }

    cout << str_hours << ":" << str_minutes << ":" << str_seconds;



    return 0;
}
```

I know this is my fault, but I am just desperate for another perspective. Thank you so much for reading this.

Comment: What have you tried? What's your *specific* problem? What does your debugger tell you? What have you researched? You are not going to just be spoon-fed a solution on SO.

Comment: @JesperJuhl OP is pretty clear on what he has tried. Hacker Rank does not let him know what's his problem, though, it's a pass-or-fail site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is its handling of border condition: it converts `12:15:00PM`, which is fifteen past noon, to invalid time `24:15:00`.

Same goes for 12 AM, midnight, which becomes 12 noon after the conversion.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was something stupidly simple that I missed.